# Get the elements that satisfy the criteria from the array in the document from MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

If I have some documents in a collection like these:

```
db.test.find()
[{
    author_id: 1
    reviews: [{article_id: 1, score: 10, ...},
              {article_id: 2, score: 7, ...},
              {article_id: 3, score_9, ...}
              ...
             ]
},
{
    author_id: 2
    reviews: [{article_id: 2, score: 8, ...},
              {article_id:4, score: 3, ...}
              ...
             ]
},
...
]
```

How can I get a list which contains all reviews satisfy the criteria, eg. **article_id equels to 2**, just like:

```
[{article_id: 2, author_id: 1, score: 7},
{article_id: 2, author_id: 2, score: 8}
...
]
```

I'm newer in MongoDB ^_^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in mongo version 3.6.

[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to output the matching review followed by [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) to combine the matching review doc with author_id.

[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the merged document to top level.

```
db.col.aggregate({
  "$replaceRoot":{
    "newRoot":{
      "$mergeObjects":[
        {"author_id":"$author_id"},
        {"$arrayElemAt":[
          {"$filter":{
            "input":"$reviews",
            "as":"rv",
            "cond":{"$eq":["$$rv.article_id",2]}
          }},
        0]}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It seems like it will return all whatever I set $$article_id

Comment: It should work. So it is hard to tell without more information.